# label-style preview in QGIS

Tags: labeling, qgis-3

When I want to load a layer style, I can open the layer properties and in symbology I get a list of styles I can choose from. On the left of each style I get a small picture that shows me a preview on how the style looks like. With one klick on the style I get a bigger preview on the top right.

[image]

I would love to have a similar drop down menu for my labels. Currently, I have a list of label styles but I can't see how they look like without opening them and applying on my layer.

[image]

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: Can you add an QGIS enhancement [Feature Request] ticket? https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues not sure we can answer your wish-list on GIS-SE.